# 会話内における「なんせ」の使い方やニュアンス、意味についての質問

Tags: meaning, manga, anime

> A:　だが 今ある最高の戦力であることには違いない。
>
> B:　ああ、そりゃあ重々承知している。
> 　　**なんせ**今回も俺ら調査兵団の作戦は博打しかねえからな。

このやりとりで「なんせ」とはどういう意味で使われていますか？文脈としては、急遽差し迫った戦争に対し、Aが今の時点で集めることができた、最低限の最高の兵士と武器が選ばれていると述べています。

また、「なんせ」、「なにしろ」、および「なにせよ」は其々で互換性がありますか？

日本語または英語のどちらかで説明していただければ嬉しいです。

Comment: この文章の出典は漫画かアニメですか？（「進撃の巨人」？）

Comment: はい、進撃の巨人のアニメです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「なんせ」は「どのみち」や「とにかく」などの、どんな事実や事情があっても、という気持ちを表します。（[goo辞書より](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%97%E3%82%8D/#jn-164538)）
英語ではanywayやanyhow、in any caseなどが相当します。

「なんせ」と「なにしろ」は類義語です（＝互換性があります）。「なにせよ」は間違いであり、辞書には載ってませんが、「なんにせよ」は同じく類義語です。他の似たような類義語には「なにせ」や「なんといっても」が挙げられます。